# How can i set individual attribute id in a function with argument?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to run the loop once ‍set attribute all elements.

HTML CODE:

```
<p class="chapter">chapter 1 text</p>
<p class="chapter">chapter 2 text</p>
<p class="chapter">chapter 3 text</p>

<p class="title">title 1 text</p>
<p class="title">title 2 text</p>
<p class="title">title 3 text</p>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
var chapter = document.querySelectorAll('.chapter')
var title = document.querySelectorAll('.title')

function setattr(className, idnum){

  for(var i = 0; i < className.length; i++){
    className[i].setAttribute('id', `${idnum}_${i}`)
  }
}
setattr(chapter, chapterId)
setattr(title, titleId)
```

Comment: What's the problem you're running into? If you define `chapterId` and `titleId`, it should work fine

Comment: I want to output like this `<p class="chapter" id="chapterId_1">chapter 1 text</p>
<p class="chapter" id="chapterId_2">chapter 2 text</p>
<p class="chapter" id="chapterId_3">chapter 3 text</p>
<p class="title" id="titleID_1">title 1 text</p>
<p class="title" id="titleID_2">title 2 text</p>
<p class="title" id="titleID_3">title 3 text</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var chapter = document.querySelectorAll('.chapter')
var title = document.querySelectorAll('.title')

function setattr(className, idnum){

  for(var i = 1; i <= className.length; i++){
    className[i].setAttribute('id', `${idnum}_${i}`)
  }
}
setattr(chapter, "chapterId")
setattr(title, "titleId")
```

```html
<p class="chapter">chapter 1 text</p>
<p class="chapter">chapter 2 text</p>
<p class="chapter">chapter 3 text</p>

<p class="title">title 1 text</p>
<p class="title">title 2 text</p>
<p class="title">title 3 text</p>
```

You need to pass 2nd argument as string

Comment: I am really sorry click mistake